How to detect another user running "netsh trace" capture?
I regularly use netsh trace start capture=yes (with a bunch of other args) to capture packet traces on Windows boxes where I am unable to install Wireshark directly. This generates a NetTrace.etl file, which I can then convert and use in Wireshark on another machine. One of our admins recently discovered a series of timestamped NetTrace.etl files being continuously deposited on one of our machines.
I thought that it might be me, but running netsh trace show status from an Administrator window returns:

"There is no trace session currently in progress."

So I assumed that some other user must be running the offending trace. How do I figure out who?
I tried using Process Explorer (as Administrator or as myself) to determine which processes have a handle open on the etl file, but it finds nothing. I tried the same with Resource Monitor and the handle command line tool, but both only identify the Windows kernel process.
Any thoughts on how I find out which user might be running this trace? And/or stop it?

Have you considered that maybe it isn’t another user running the trace session? It could be a system process or event that you don’t know about. That would be my first guess.

I didn't.  But that just pushes my question out to "How do I tell what is running the trace?"

Have you checked the event log? Maybe some kind of service, process or something ran the offending trace. Check all of them, and it should be quick and simple considering you have said the all of the traces are timestamped.
Now if it's a process or Service, try disabling it.
And see it the traces keep happening.
